# How to add picture to Excel instead link to file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have small VBA form to insert picture to a cell but if the file image was deletd or renamed the image on Excel file was missing too, this is my sample code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Sheet3.Activate
  Dim uk_gbr As Range
  Dim gbr As Object
  Dim tp_gbr As String
  Dim I As Integer
    
  tp_gbr = Application.GetOpenFilename("Pilih Gambar (*.jfif; *.jpg; *.png)," & _
    "*.jfif; *.jpg; *.png", MultiSelect = True)
    
  If tp_gbr <> CStr(False) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set uk_gbr = Application.InputBox("Pilih Cell:", "Masukkan Gambar", ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
      uk_gbr.Activate
      Set gbr = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(tp_gbr)
      gbr.ShapeRange.Height = 249.12
  End If
  
  Set uk_gbr = Nothing
  Set gbr = Nothing
Sheet1.Activate
End Sub
```

I'm new on vba so this code was search through internet.

Comment: Use ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture, with LinkToFile:= False and SaveWithDocument:=True

Comment: please write the exact code @milo5m im new with vba :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
Set gbr = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=tp_gbr, _
                                        linktofile:=msoFalse, _
                                        savewithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                                        Left:=0, _
                                        Top:=0, _
                                        Width:=-1, _
                                        Height:=-1) ' -1 retains the width/height of the original picture
gbr.Height = 249.12 'gbr.ShapeRange.Height = 249.12 'doesn't work here
```

Also you could use `Left:=ActiveCell.Left, Top:=ActiveCell.Top` in place of `Left:=0, Top:=0`

The following code inserts the picture on the location of the uk_gbr cell and fits the image size to the range dimension.

Just replace

```
Set gbr = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(tp_gbr)
gbr.ShapeRange.Height = 249.12
```

with

```
Set gbr = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=tp_gbr, _
                                        linktofile:=msoFalse, _
                                        savewithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                                        Left:=uk_gbr.left, _
                                        Top:=uk_gbr.top, _
                                        Width:=uk_gbr.width, _
                                        Height:=uk_gbr.height)
```

Comment: yess, this code work for importing a picture instead of link, but how about picture size and cell placement, i want to import this picture to selected cell which is this code ` Set uk_gbr = Application.InputBox("Pilih Cell:", "Masukkan Gambar", ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)` and resize it to the size off the cell which is this code `      gbr.ShapeRange.Height = 249.12` thanks for the help :)

Comment: I've added the support for positioning and Height

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider marking it as such

Comment: thankyou @milo5m this code works perfecly i just edit on the part width and height, offcourse searh trough internet again, i just edit this part `Width:=uk_gbr.width, _
                                        Height:=uk_gbr.height)` with the -1 and lock the aspect ratio, so my image not stretched on cell, again.. thanks for helping me out milo5m

Comment: but how if i just type code in sheet1 cell a1, a2, a3, a4 let say i write panda, monkey, dog and cat, then the picture of the panda, monkey, dog and cat will appear in sheet2 cell a3 b3 and a5 b5 because cell a2 b2 and a4 and b4 is for numbering, assuming i have picture of this animal in my folder (D:\OneDrive\Desktop\animal)

in above code i must find the picture and store it on specific cell